# Can we create windows 10 desktop(uwp) apps using phonegap?

Tags: uwp, phonegap, windows-10-desktop

Can we create windows 10 desktop(uwp) apps using phonegap ?

Thanks,
Noorul.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently yes, [since 2016](https://phonegap.com/blog/2016/04/25/windows-10-and-phonegap-cli-6_1-now-on-build/).

Check also [Apache Cordova's documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/index.html) on how to setup your Phonegap app and dev environment for it.